Reload built-in preview with cache cleaning in PhpStorm
How to reload the built-in preview with cache cleaning in PhpStorm 2024 by using a shortcut, like in Chrome by pressing Shift + F5 (to get new result of rand())?
In PhpStorm 2024, I didn't find any default shortcut that directly mimics Chrome's Shift + F5 to reload the built-in preview with cache.
